# Map Reduce program creates an empty directory on execution

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am running the below Map reduce code to calculate sum and average length of words starting with each english alphabet.

```
For example : If the doc only contains the word 'and' 5 times
letter | total words | average length
   a        5               3
```

The mapreduce program is as below:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class LetterWiseAvgLengthV1
{

    public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>
    {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            String st [] = value.toString().split("\\s+");          

            for(String word :  st) {

                String wordnew=word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]",""); 
                String firstLetter = wordnew.substring(0, 1);

                if(!wordnew.isEmpty()){
                    // write ('a',3) if the word is and             
                    context.write(new Text(firstLetter), new Text(String.valueOf(wordnew.length())));                   
                }
                else continue; 
            }
        }
    }


    public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text>
    {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {
            int sum=0,count=0;

            for (Text val : values)
            {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(val.toString());
                count+= 1;
            }

            float avg=(sum/(float)count);
            String op="Average length of " + count + " words = " + avg;
            context.write(new Text(key), new Text(op));
        }
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "wordLenAvgCombiner");

        job.setJarByClass(LetterWiseAvgLengthV1.class);

        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

When I execute the program below on a text document, it creates an empty output directory in HDFS. There are no failures during execution, but the output folder is always empty

Comment: Um: "There are no failures during execution" : I have my doubts about that. Its sometimes hard to find the correct log and well sometimes also quite hard to spot. I think there should be something in the logs.

Comment: Add some logging and run against a small test dataset. Also ensure you handle situations where the input string (or words in it) are null. You don't want your entire MapReduce job to die because of one empty line.